# What does @dimen/activity_vertical_margin do?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

In the following code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.ashokaquiz.MainActivity">
```

What does `@dimen/activity_vertical_margin` do? I cannot find any documentation for it. I know what padding is. I just want to know about the `@dimen/activity_vertical_margin` bit.

Thank you.

Comment: These are the dimensions defined in dimens.xml which is used for providing padding

Answer (score 49, accepted):

@dimen refers to **dimension** and it's a file where you define dimensions to use them later from in any layout file.

It's located in `res/values/dimens`. Here's what a sample of the file look like:

```
 <resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
 </resources>
```

Here activity_veritcal_margin = 16 dp.

and to use it like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
```

Here we give this linear layout a bottom padding with 16dp.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`@dimen/activity_vertical_margin` or whatever `@dimen/whatever_key_name` is a reference to a dimension that probably is saved in your `projectname/src/main/res/value/dimen.xml` file

In android you can save several values for example dimensions, strings, integers, drawables...

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) you can find more information about it