# What is the paddingBottom dimension?

Tags: android

I am writing am app in Android Studio and I found somewhere like this in the xml files under layout.

```
android:paddingBottom="dimension(1025)
```

Can someone tell me what is this?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [android:paddingBottom](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:paddingBottom)?

Comment: @PJProudhon I have read the documentation but there it is only int so px, sp, dp but this dimension made me confused.!

Answer (score 2):

A `padding` is some "empty space".

While `margin` adds some space *ouside* the view, a `padding` adds it *inside*.

Comment: Exactly, and maybe it refers to a xml file too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41368901 - Thank you very much for your insights ;)

Comment: Well, normally the file is calles `/res/values/dimens.xml`. But it could be whatever. The resource file name is actually only important for us human developers, not for the IDE itself.

Comment: Oh my friend... do you believe I did not have that closer look yet? It's our final days here on the academic semester and I am very busy... Great coincidence, just yesterday I was missing my "Proppelerheads Rebirth" on my pc.. missing some sound experiences truly and for a while I keep playing those retrowave-synthwave collections on utube :D - have to give some lessons on brazilian music to you! On the 70's we had a bunch of synth psychedelic here...

Comment: Thank you! I will check it now.