# Checkboxes gets wrong position on Android 5.02 device

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, checkbox

I have a fragment with 12 CheckBoxes, 6 on the left side and 6 on the rigth side.
In a Moto E5 with Android 8.1 looks ok(debug) as in my Android Studio does in the preview window.

Now I just installed to another phone, LG G2 with Android 5.0.2 and the CheckBoxes from the right  side appear on the left side.
Those CheckBoxes are RTL and the left one don't.

**Expected**

[image]

**Wrong**

[image]

What can be the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/filtroEventos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FiltroEventos">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/filtro1_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Disp." />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/filtro1_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:text="Disp." />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/filtro1_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="Disp." />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/filtro1_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filtro1_3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:text="Entr." />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/filtro1_5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filtro1_4"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"

        android:text="Evento" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/filtro1_6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filtro1_5"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"

        android:text="Evento" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/filtro3_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="183dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:text="Rest." />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/filtro3_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="183dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:text="Rest." />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/filtro3_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="183dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:text="Rest." />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/filtro3_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filtro1_3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="192dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="113dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:text="Sal." />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/filtro3_5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filtro1_4"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="183dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="147dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:text="Rest." />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/filtro3_6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filtro1_5"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="183dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="182dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:text="Rest." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="103dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Alarmas" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="93dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="Supervision" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="94dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:text="Problemas" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="102dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
        android:text="Accesos" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="103dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="157dp"
        android:text="Sistema" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="114dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
        android:text="Test" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="#FF0F28B4" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="171dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="#0F28B4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add the problematic and expected screenshot with question .

Comment: @ADM Ready. Pictures added.

Comment: try to use ConstraintLayout

Comment: It works! It is possible to disable the automatic rotation?

Comment: Add something like `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` or `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in the AndroidManifest.xml:  
`<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the android version, it is with the screen density.so the solution is that create a dimens resource file specify marginStart and marginTop for each screen density.

[Follow the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368739/what-does-dimen-activity-vertical-margin-do)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with specific Android version. 
If you want to use use RelativeLayout then refer below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/filtroEventos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/filtro1_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="Disp." />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/filtro1_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/filtro1_1"
            android:text="Disp." />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/filtro1_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/filtro1_2"
            android:text="Disp." />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/filtro1_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/filtro1_3"
            android:text="Entr." />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/filtro1_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/filtro1_4"
            android:text="Evento" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/filtro1_6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/filtro1_5"

            android:text="Evento" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/firstView"
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/firstRelativeLayout"
        android:background="#FF0F28B4" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/firstView">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="Alarmas" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Supervision" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Problemas" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="Accesos" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:text="Sistema" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:text="Test" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/thirdRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/secondView">
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/filtro3_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="Rest." />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/filtro3_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/filtro3_1"
            android:text="Rest." />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/filtro3_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/filtro3_2"
            android:text="Rest." />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/filtro3_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/filtro3_3"
            android:text="Sal." />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/filtro3_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/filtro3_4"
            android:text="Rest." />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/filtro3_6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/filtro3_5"
            android:text="Rest." />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/secondView"
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/secondRelativeLayout"
        android:background="#0F28B4" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you are using RelativeLayout then try to use `android:layout_below` or `android:layout_toEndOf` so that you can give proper position to respective TextView, Checkboxes. Don't use static Margin to give position.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your layout properly try `LinearLayout` with `weight`

Please try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight=".34"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".17"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/filtro1_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Disp."/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/filtro1_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Disp." />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/filtro1_3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Disp." />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/filtro1_4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Entr." />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/filtro1_5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Evento" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/filtro1_6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Evento" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_weight=".01"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FF0F28B4" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".17"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Alarmas"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Supervision" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Problems" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Accesos" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Sistema" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Test" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_weight=".01"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FF0F28B4" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight=".34"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".17"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/filtro3_1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                        android:text="Rest." />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/filtro3_2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                        android:text="Rest." />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/filtro3_3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                        android:text="Rest." />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/filtro3_4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                        android:text="Sal." />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/filtro3_5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                        android:text="Rest." />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight=".16"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/filtro3_6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                        android:text="Rest." />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The output of above code is:

[image]

I hope its work for you.